# не могу установить куки в POST запросе Node.js

Tags: node.js, cookie, сессия

не могу установить дефолтную куку express-session - connect.sid

Создал новые файлы: test.html и test.js

вот код: 
test.js

```
var express = require("express");     
var session = require("express-session");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

var app = express();    
var port = 4000;

app.use(bodyParser());    
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
     secret: "Secret word"
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,
 Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.use("/login",function (req,res) {
    var login = req.body.user;
    var pass = req.body.password;

    console.log(login);    
    console.log("Work");
    res.send("Work");
});

app.listen(port);
```

а вот test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:4000/login" name="login" id="login">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn"  value="Send">
</form>
<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var data = $("#login").serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost:4000/login",
                data: data,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                }
            })

    })

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

если вручную открыть новую вкладку, и перейти по такому пути `http://localhost/4000/login` тогда кука `connect.sid` создаться.

И еще хотел спросить по поводу сессий, что бы мне обяснили.

Я думаю должно быть так:

Вводиш логин и пароль, он отправляеться на сервер, там проверяеться есть ли такой юзер в БД, и подоходит ли пароль. Если да, то создать ключ(ид сессии).
И вернуть на клиент например объект `user.auth = true` , на клиенте проверить , если етот объект `= true` , то перенаправить например на страницу `MyOffice.html`.
А вот тут вопрос.
Как на странице `MyOffice.html` проверить авторизирован ли юзер? я думаю по куки `connect.sid` , так?
Извините за ошибки, и объясните мне пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже понял) я не предоставил статические файлы)

нужно  убрать :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,
 Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

и дописать

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));
 app.get("/",function (req, res) {

    });
```

в папку "public" кинуть  html файлы, и заходить на сайт нужно под доменом сервера: http://localhost:4000/ , чтобы сервер вернул html страницу) а  я запускал через WebStorm и адрес был такой: http://localhost:63342/Tvolex/FirstApp/index.html .